How to animate a list in Angular when data is changing dynamically?
I want to animate a list of elements over several pages. The list is divided into chunks of 4 elements per page. At the start, the first page is displayed, with each element being shown one after the other. After 1 second, these elements should be removed one after the other and the second page should be shown, etc. At the end of the list, the first page should be started again.
pages = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,10,11,12]
]

That works quite well. The problem occurs when the list is to be replaced with new data. Somehow the animation now seems to be running in parallel.
I want all animations to stop completely when new data is received. Currently running animations should be canceled. How can I solve the problem?
Is there perhaps a completely different solution?
Here is a link to a stackblitz to demonstrate the problem (each 5sec the list data is replaced). See the console and the page index which demonstrates the problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ffwbbh

I got rid of a lot of unnecessary code. I used this stackblitz as reference to solve the issue.
Basically, we need to create a new div element that contains the animation defintion on the child element.
Then I merge the datasets using the spread operator on the rows property.
Then on each setInterval, I increment the index property and store the indexed sub array, this will cause the animation to happen automatically.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import {
  trigger,
  transition,
  style,
  animate,
  query,
  stagger,
  state,
} from '@angular/animations';
import { Subscription, interval } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    Page {{ currentIndex + 1 }} <div [@listAnimation2]="isAnimating"
  (@listAnimation2.done)="isAnimating = false">
    <div *ngFor="let item of currentPage;trackBy: trackByFn; let i = index" >
      <div [@listAnimation]="'in'">{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`div { margin: 5px; font-size: 24px; text-align: center; }`],
  animations: [
    trigger('listAnimation', [
      state('in', style({ opacity: 1 })),
      transition(':enter', [style({ opacity: 0 }), animate(600)]),
      transition(':leave', animate(600, style({ opacity: 0 }))),
    ]),
    trigger('listAnimation2', [
      transition('* => *', [
        // query(
        //   ':leave',
        //   [stagger(500, [animate(1000, style({ opacity: 0 }))])],
        //   { optional: true }
        // ),
        query(
          ':enter',
          [
            style({ opacity: 0 }),
            stagger(500, [animate(1000, style({ opacity: 1 }))]),
          ],
          { optional: true }
        ),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  list1: any[] = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12],
  ];

  list2: any[] = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
    ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
  ];

  rows: any[] = [];
  currentIndex: number = 0;
  currentPage: number[] = [];
  animationState = '';
  isAnimating = false;

  private dataSubscription: any;

  trackByFn(index: number, item: any) {
    return item;
  }

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rows = [...this.list1, ...this.list2];
    this.currentPage = this.rows[this.currentIndex];
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    // Simulate new data arriving periodically
    this.dataSubscription = interval(5000).subscribe(() => {
      this.updateRows();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.dataSubscription) {
      this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  updateRows() {
    if (this.currentIndex < this.rows.length - 1) {
      this.currentIndex++;
    } else {
      this.currentIndex = 0;
    }
    this.currentPage = this.rows[this.currentIndex];
    this.isAnimating = true;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Hi Naran, thx for your support! Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my issue. Your example shows the entire list at once. What I want to try to achieve is that each element is animates one after each other (therefore the complex anim). show "1", when down show "2" etc. If the whole page is done, move to page 2 etc.
In such a scnario it kills the animation when changing the list.

@Lars Is this the correct way? Stackblitz Demo

the animation looks fine! But the real issue still exists: When I modify the rows during the runtime of the animation - it breaks. Please note that the interval of changing the rows is just for the stackblitz. Typically new values will be send to the component via the Input() Please see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-u5hxsa

@Lars like this stackblitz ?

that looks great.  will try to build it into my code. Thx a lot for your help!

May I can ask you again for support, please? After a closer look to your code I noticed that it doesn't fit really the requirements. In my previous version I used a single animation (benefit no need for a subscription and fadein/out, delay etc is all managed by the animation. The point is that it worked in Angular 17. But since I changed to v18 is broke. The very first animation works fine but then it wont continue and turns me nuts. Pls can you take a further look to this https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kz3ver I hope that you can find my mistake and why it isn't working
